# Как сглаживать пики периодических задач на оси времени?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть сотни тыс. периодических заданий, где каждое должно выполняться со своим собственным периодом повтора: раз в 12 часов, у других раз в 15 минут, например.

Помимо периода *P*, у задания ещё два параметра: время *T*, когда его уже можно начать выполнять (не раньше), и коэффициент срочности *K*, который означает, как быстро с момента *T* линейно растёт приоритет этого задания. При прочих равных `K = 1/Period`.

Рабочий процесс дискретный, запускается «шагами» раз в 5 минут по крону. Каждый раз берет охапку заданий, из тех, что уже можно исполнять, ориентируясь на приоритеты на данный момент этих заданий, и не больше, чем своя «ёмкость», которая ограничена.

**Ситуация:** в один момент времени внезапно пришла сразу 1000 новых заданий. При ёмкости в 300 задач за один шаг такой пик вызовет лавину задержек у всех задач. Поэтому эту 1000 заданий надо постепенно раскидать, чтобы они шли не в единый момент, а +-. Но «разъехались» они по этим новым своим позициям не мгновенно, а в течение какого-то времени. Напр. можно ограничивать скорость «сползания» каждой задачи в % от её периода.

**Вопрос**: как корректировать фазу периодических заданий, чтобы пики нагрузки «размазывались» по времени? При этом надо, чтобы если какое-то задание и сдвигалось, оно делало это постепенно, маленькими шагами. Тут важно, чтобы интервал выполнения каждого задания был максимально приближен к целевому – у кого-то это 12 часов, у кого-то 15 минут.

По аналогии с физическим миром, как я себе представляю, это похоже на насыпание частиц (кристаллов песка) на поверхность. Чтобы песчинки в итоге распределились более ли менее равномерно, надо поверхность встряхивать, снова и снова. Каждый раз частицы стремятся удалиться от соседей. И это постепенно приводит к равномерному распределению.

Может, есть известный алгоритм, описывающий такую модель?

Comment: время последнего выполнения задания у вас сохраняется?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin сохраняется где-то отдельно, в рамках алгоритма это не нужно, т.к. сразу после очередного выполнения, задание само себя переносит вперед на период: `T = Tпред + Period`

Comment: так `T` у вас «плавающий»? по-моему, это существенно упрощает требующийся алгоритм.

Comment: Если бы `T` фиксировался, задача не имела решения. А так он плавающий, но с «вязкостью».

Comment: смотря что понимать под `T`. я понял так, что у задания есть некое `T0` (возможно, в будущем), а запускать его надо в момент `T0+n*P`, где `n=0, 1, 2, …, ∞`.

Comment: Всё так, и `T` – это очередное `n*P + T0 + dF1 + dF2 + .. dFn`, где `dFx` – эти индивидуальные микрокоррекции на каждом шаге, которые мне надо как-то разумно считать, об этом и вопрос. Я не храню `T0` и просто в очередной раз выполнив задачу, ставлю ей же новый «будильник».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно организовать приоритетную очередь заданий. Постараюсь объяснить. Допустим у Вас есть 1000 заданий, каждое со своей периодичностью. Т.е. Вы знаете, в какие моменты времени каждая из этих задач должна в следующий раз запуститься. В таком случае при наступлении некоторого момента времени, когда должна запуститься одна или несколько задач, Вы их не запускаете, а ставите в очередь определенным образом. Например, ёмкость рабочего процесса 300 задач. В некоторый момент времени должно запуститься 450 задач. 300 из них Вы запускаете на выполнение (задержка 0*T), остальные остаются в очереди. Через 5 минут Вы должны запустить еще 170 задач. Вы эти 170 ставите в начало очереди, так что бы рабочий процесс забрал сначала их (задержка 0*T), затем он доберёт до свой емкости из прошлых задач еще 130 (задержка 1*T). Через следующие 5 минут все повторится. При этом есть вероятность, общее количество заданий превысит физический предел обработки `24 часа * 12 задач в час * 300 заданий в обработке`. В этом случае часть заданий, которая превышает это число, вообще не будет обрабатываться. Однако и от этого можно избавиться, достаточно для каждого задания отслеживать, сколько оно находится в очереди. Если это значение превысило некоторый порог (необходимо будет рассчитать или определить опытным путём), то повышать приоритет задания, сдвигая его в начало очереди, т.е. запускать "принудительно". Если у Вас задания нескольких разных типов, можно ввести более развитую приоритетную систему.

Comment: Как и в предложении Alexander Barakin', у задач, не влезших в «автобус» путь один – опоздать еще больше. В то время, как, эта пачка совпавших в один момент времени, как мне кажется, могла бы «договориться между собой»: *– Мы все в наш автобус не влезем, давайте рассосредоточимся.* – И случайным образом разбросать их немного, с нормальным распределением, в пределах максимального отклонения, допустим, в 10% от периода задачи. Как в сторону чуть позже, так и в сторону чуть раньше.  **Т.е.** может, надо находить локальные максимумы и «размывать» их целенаправленно?

Comment: А общий список заданий и их периодичность заранее известен? Или возможно появление новых заданий во время работы системы?

Comment: Система живая: задания появляются и исчезают постоянно и непредсказуемо (пользователями сервиса). В случае приближения к исчерпыванию емкости запускаются доп. сервера и рабочие процессы с них.

Comment: Вам может быть полезна следующая абстракция:

Comment: 1. Найдите НОК (наименьшее общее кратное) для периодов всех задач на данный момент времени.   2. На этом временном промежутке нужно разложить "гребенки" из моментов запуска каждого задания. Причем эти "гребенки" - цикличны, т.е. если первый запуск уходит в относительном времени в -1, то этот запуск появится в самый последний момент.    3. Затем находим момент времени, когда должно запуститься максимальное число задания (любой из этих моментов) и начинаем его разгружать - одну задачу двигаем влево по оси времени, вторую вправо.  4. Повторять пп 2-3 до достижения некоторого результата.

Answer (score 1):

для каждого задания надо подсчитать такое значение:

```
k=K*(t-T+d)
```

где:

- `T` (минуты) — время очередного запуска задания (запускать не раньше этого момента)
- `t` (минуты) — текущий момент времени
- `K` — коэффициент срочности (чем он выше, тем приоритетнее задание)
- `d` (минуты) — допустимое время «преждевременного» запуска

сортируем список по убыванию и отбрасываем отрицательные `k` (для них время запуска ещё не наступило), получаем `N` «кандидатов» на запуск.

для возможности «размазывания» имеет смысл сохранять несколько последних `N` для вычисления какого-нибудь среднего (например, арифметического) из них. обозначим его `Nс`.

если `N > Nс` то «отбрасываем» часть последних заданий из списка (допустим, половину от `N-Nс`), но только те, для которых `k` меньше некоторого порога (например, `1/10`).

все оставшиеся в списке задания отправляем на выполнение (естественно, не более первых трёхсот — такова у вас максимальная «ёмкость»).

у «отброшенных» заданий с каждым циклом будет «нарастать» величина `k`, и они будут перемещаться вверх по списку, тем самым увеличивается их вероятность запуска на очередном цикле.

Comment: При единоразовом добавлении сразу 1000 задач в один момент времени (с предполагаемым стартом в этот же момент), далее они *разбегутся* между собой только за счёт того, что часть из них не успела на очередной «автобус». Т.е. все они уйдут в сторону задержки относительно изначального плана.

Может, есть смысл где-то внедрить *случайность* для разброса заданий относительно начальной своей фазы в обе стороны?

Comment: честно говоря, не вижу смысла во внесении *случайности* (вероятно потому, что не знаю всех деталей стоящей перед вами задачи, или невнимательно читал вопрос), но если она необходима, то, конечно, вносите. // ещё можно случайным образом сортировать список (для заданий с равными значениями `k`), или сортировать по двум критериям — сначала по значению `k`, а затем по `K` и/или `P`.

Comment: @Sergiks, изложенный мною подход основан на «срезании» и постепенном «размазывании» периодических «всплесков». если вам требуется изначальное, с самого первого цикла, перераспределение заданий, то моё предложение, конечно, вам не подойдёт.

Comment: Срезание прекрасно. Как бы заставить его работать в обе стороны от изначально нацеленного времени? Напр. на 15:00 по расписанию будет 400 задач с периодом в 12ч. Почему часть из них случайно не перекинуть на 5 минут раньше? И часть на 5 мин. позже.

Comment: @Sergiks, то есть, допустимо запускать задания чуть раньше времени `T`? тогда можно добавить в формулу для `k` некую дельту для «преждевременного» запуска. возможно, не в виде конкретного количества минут, а в виде какой-то функции, например, от `P`. внёс исправление в ответ.